# Distance Between two Probability Vectors from Different Sample Sizes

Tags: statistics

I have several different samples taking categorial values. For each sample I calculate the probablity of every value. I am taking one sample as a benchmark, call it Q. I want to measure the distance between the probablity vector derived from every sample to Q.

My understanding is that the classical ways to go about it is to use Euclidean distance or Jensen-Shannon Divergence. I use both. They are highly correlated.

However, my problem is that each sample is of different size. Some samples include hundreds of observations, while other a few dozens. I see that systematically the smaller samples are calculated as being further away from Q. This makes sense, as noise plays a bigger role.

My question is how do I fix the metrics I use, to shrink distance when are calculated based on a smaller sample?

Thanks!